# Why is my Formik form not submitting when I have no validation?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, semantic-ui-react

I'm working on building a registration form using Semantic UI React and Formik.

No matter what I've tried, I am unable to get the `onSubmit` event to trigger upon attempting to submit the form, even though I've temporarily disabled form validation.

I'm simply trying to just `console.log()` a message, not even worried about the form's values at this time.

As far as I can see, it should be working...but I've also noticed that initial values are not being populated from that variable either.

I noticed at some point someone else had developed a wrapper for Semantic UI React to combine the functionality of both libraries, but didn't have much luck with that either (unless I was also using that incorrectly).

Should I just ditch the `<Formik />` component (even though it seems to be the most optimal way to use it) and adopt the React hook implementation instead?

I'm at a loss, not sure what I'm doing wrong unless it's an oversight.

**RegisterForm.tsx (component)**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
// import * as Yup from 'yup';

// Interface
import { RegisterData } from '../../interfaces/RegisterData';

// Component
export const RegisterForm = () => {

    const initValues: RegisterData = {
        given_name: 'Test',
        family_name: 'Test2',
        email: '',
        phone: '',
        username: '',
        password: '',
        confirm_password: '',
        agreeTOS: false
    };

    // const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    //     given_name: Yup.string().max(20, "Must be 20 characters or less!").required("Required!"),
    //     family_name: Yup.string().max(20, "Must be 20 characters or less!").required("Required!"),
    //     email: Yup.string().email("Invalid e-mail address!").required("Required!"),
    //     phone: Yup.string().matches(/^[+]*[(]?[0-9]{1,4}[)]?[-\s./0-9]*$/i, "Invalid phone number!")
    //         .min(8, "Must be at least  8 digits!").max(15, "Must be 15 digits or less!").required(),
    //     password: Yup.string().min(8, "Must be at least 8 characters!").required(),
    //     confirm_password: Yup.string().oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], "Passwords do not match!").required("Required!"),
    //     agreeTOS: Yup.boolean().oneOf([true], "Terms must be accepted!").required("Terms must be accepted!")
    // })

    // const handleSubmit = async (values: RegisterData) => {
    //     setTimeout(() => {
    //         console.log("Values: ", values);
    //     }, 2000);
    // }

    return (
        <Grid.Row>
            <Grid.Column width={10}>
                <Formik
                    onSubmit={() => { console.log('test'); }}
                    initialValues={initValues}
                >
                    {({ isSubmitting }) => (
                        <Form>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.Row>
                                    <Grid.Column width={16}>
                                        <Form.Group widths="equal">
                                            <Form.Input name="given_name" label="First Name" fluid />
                                            <Form.Input name="family_name" label="Last Name" fluid />
                                        </Form.Group>
                                    </Grid.Column>
                                </Grid.Row>
                                <Grid.Row>
                                    <Grid.Column width={8}>
                                        <Button type="submit" color="orange" fluid loading={isSubmitting}>Submit Form</Button>
                                    </Grid.Column>
                                    <Grid.Column width={8}>
                                        <Button type="submit" color="grey" fluid>Submit Form</Button>
                                    </Grid.Column>
                                </Grid.Row>
                            </Grid>
                        </Form>
                    )}

                </Formik>
            </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
    )
}
```

**RegisterData.ts (interface to hold form data)**

```js
export interface RegisterData {
    email: string;
    phone: string;
    username: string;
    given_name: string;
    family_name: string;
    password: string;
    confirm_password: string;
    agreeTOS: boolean;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!   I'm really confused, I feel like I probably overlooked something here, but I don't know what it could be.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you have to wire your inputs to Formik using `<Field>` component. Take a look docs here https://formik.org/docs/api/field . I'm not sure if it will work rightaway but try something like this: `<Field name="given_name" component={Form.Input} />`

Answer (score 0):

Formik is generic form library and doesn't work out of the box with third party form fields components.

What you need to do is whether bind your components manually using  or useField API or use ready to use wrappers https://github.com/JT501/formik-semantic-ui-react which add formik binding to semantic-ui componets